# PHP Image not showing in HTML using img element

Tags: php, html

Hello there i have a php file with the included:

The image shows properly when i access the PHP file, however when I try to show it in the HTML template, it shows as the little img with a crack in it, so basically saying "image not found"

```
<img src="http://konvictgaming.com/status.php?channel=blindsniper47">
```

is what i'm using to display it in the HTML template, however it just doesn't seem to want to show, I've tried searching with next to no results for my specific issue, although I'm certain I've probably searched the wrong title

adding code from the OP below

```
$clientId = '';             // Register your application and get a client ID at http://www.twitch.tv/settings?section=applications
$online = 'online.png';     // Set online image here
$offline = 'offline.png';   // Set offline image here
$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/'.strtolower($channelName).'?client_id='.$clientId), true);

if ($json_array['stream'] != NULL) {
    $channelTitle = $json_array['stream']['channel']['display_name'];
    $streamTitle = $json_array['stream']['channel']['status'];
    $currentGame = $json_array['stream']['channel']['game'];

    echo "<img src='$online' />";
} else {
    echo "<img src='$offline' />";
}
```

Comment: You are not referring to an image. The actual image URL is http://konvictgaming.com/offline.png

Comment: You are referring to `http://konvictgaming.com/offline.png` image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your status.php file, where you output the markup of `<img src=...` change it to read as follows

```
$image = file_get_contents("offline.png");
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $image;
```

Which will send an actual image for the request instead of sending markup. markup is not valid `src` for an `img` tag.

UPDATE your code modified below.

```
$clientId = '';             // Register your application and get a client ID at http://www.twitch.tv/settings?section=applications
$online = 'online.png';     // Set online image here
$offline = 'offline.png';   // Set offline image here
$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/'.strtolower($channelName).'?client_id='.$clientId), true);

header("Content-Type: image/png");
$image = null;
if ($json_array['stream'] != NULL) {
    $channelTitle = $json_array['stream']['channel']['display_name'];
    $streamTitle = $json_array['stream']['channel']['status'];
    $currentGame = $json_array['stream']['channel']['game'];

    $image = file_get_contents($online);
} else {
    $image = file_get_contents($offline);        
}
echo $image;
```

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm pretty crap when it comes to php, could you give me the full example of what it would look like? as im unsure as to where it should go / remove/ change xD

i basically just want it to Show the image for Online/Offline, the Current game/ Title isnt needed

so in theory i just want <img src='$offline'>

Comment: i need to see bit more of your code where you echo your current markup

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Mn7gM7D4

But for some reason now im getting 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/isykonvi/public_html/stream/status.php on line 3

Comment: @DanielStarmer i've added update code you can copy paste directly.

Comment: it worked!, thank you so much mate!, although i do have another issue, shall i open a new thing or do you think you can help? it's with the same status.php, I basically want it so that when they access status.php directly from the directory it returns the print:
 
ERROR: Please put a stream user in your link.
ex: http://konvictgaming.com/status.php?channel=konvictgaming

Comment: we can render an image with that message in it. better you ask a question like that. :) i am having dinner at the moment

Answer (score 6):

The url is not an image, it is a webpage with the following content

```
<img src='offline.png' alt='Offline' />
```

Webpages cannot be displayed as images. You will need to edit the page to only transmit the actual image, with the correct http-headers.

You can probably find some help on this by googling for "php dynamic image".

Comment: Sorry it seems Stack removed the PHP file that is linked to it which is echoing my Images

http://pastebin.com/cbtKkWS1

As you can see it echo's the image & returns it properly, when X person goes Online/offline on their stream the image changes accordingly, I have previously  img scrd a php file like this one, i just can't seem to figure out what is wrong with it in this instance!

Comment: Well yes, it's echoing html correctly. So it looks fine when you open it as a webpage. But you need the page to act as an image instead of as a html-page  if you want to use it in an `<img />`.

Answer (score 2):

Specify in the HTTP header that it's a PNG (or whatever) image!

(By default they are interpreted as text/html)

Comment: Sorry it seems Stack removed the PHP file that is linked to it which is echoing my Images

http://pastebin.com/cbtKkWS1

As you can see it echo's the image & returns it properly, when X person goes Online/offline on their stream the image changes accordingly, I have previously  img scrd a php file like this one, i just can't seem to figure out what is wrong with it in this instance!

Comment: Add `header('Content-Type: image/png');` to the first line in the file you linked.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you change the picture dynmaclly on this page.

Easiest way with least changes will just be using an iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://konvictgaming.com/status.php?channel=blindsniper47">    </iframe>
```